# Is $2\cdot(1+1)=(1+1)2 = (1+1) * 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I hope my question is not too basic, but let's say I dropped out of Uni because of uhm... math.

I'm writing a parser to calculate math expressions that I extract from strings.

For this, I need to know what to accept as valid input.

Therefore my question if an expression like `(1+1)2` is valid and to be interpreted as `(1+1) * 2`?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I have seen the $*$ symbol used to denote custom operations in some questions. For example, the asker might say, $1*1=11,4*2=42$ and then ask what $3*3$ is. In which case, it would be 33, not 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing the parser, so ultimately you get to decide what is valid syntax. That being said `(1 + 1)2` is certainly a valid way of writing `(1 + 1) * 2`.

And to add to the title of the post

```
2 * (1 + 1) = 2(1 + 1) = (1 + 1)2 = (1 + 1) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $2\cdot(1+1) = (1+1)\cdot 2$.

The [[commutative property of multiplication][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Properties)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Properties) allows you to swap the two terms multiplied without changing the product.

For example,
$a\cdot b = b\cdot a$

So, if you apply this, $(1+1)\cdot 2$ can be switched around to $2\cdot (1+1)$
This is just like the commutative property of addition, where $a+b=b+a$ where you can change the orders of the terms around.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with real numbers, we have left distributivity of multiplication over addition: for all $x,y,z$,

$$x(y+z)=xy+xz;$$

and right distributivity,

$$(y+z)x=yx+zx.$$

Now applying commutativity of multiplication, we get

$$x(y+z)=xy+xz=yx+zx=(y+z)x.$$

Also, yes, juxtaposition is usually understood to mean multiplication.